# java jsoup parse how to parse html

Tags: java, jsoup

Is there any possible way to parse

```
<a href="/summoner/userName=Huhi" class="Link">Huhi</a>
```

in html:

```
<a href="/summoner/userName=Huhi" class="Link">Huhi</a>
<a href="/summoner/userName=Huhi" class="Link">White</a>
<a href="/summoner/userName=Huhi" class="Link">Angle</a>
```

Output:

```
Huhi
White
Angle
```

Comment: `select` each `a` and print its `text()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your document and get all the a[href] links, iterate through these links and get the text they contain. Like so:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
 for (Element link : links) {
     String text = link.text();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just select `a` and iterate the `elements` and print

```
String html ="<a href=\"/summoner/userName=Huhi\" class=\"Link\">Huhi</a>\n" +
                "<a href=\"/summoner/userName=Huhi\" class=\"Link\">White</a>\n" +
                "<a href=\"/summoner/userName=Huhi\" class=\"Link\">Angle</a>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements links = doc.select("a");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.text());

        }
```

For further reference check this link [selector-syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: I got this far already, now i'm having this problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238695/java-jsoup-remove-new-lines/39240666?noredirect=1#comment65818367_39240666