# java jsoup remove new lines

Tags: java, jsoup

```
        for (int x = 0; x < 8000; x += 50) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("localhost.com/"+x).get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link: links) {
                String text = link.text();
                System.out.println(text);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Which would give an output like this:

```
Adrian Riven

HalfSugar No Ice

Yassuo

Amandadog

P1 Sloosh
```

Is there anyway to remove the empty lines? so it'd look like this as the output:

```
Adrian Riven
HalfSugar No Ice
Yassuo
Amandadog
P1 Sloosh
```

i've tried
text.replace("\n", "");
text.replaceAll("\r?\n", "")

Edit like this, this did not work for me
Didnt try the other one

```
   Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link: links) {
            Document docs = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(links));
            docs.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
            String text = link.text()+link.text();
            System.out.println(text.replace("Show More", ""));
```

Example html:

```
</td>
    <td class="SummonerName Cell">
        <a href="/summoner/userName=Cris" class="Link">Cris</a>
    </td>
                <td class="TierRank Cell">Challenger</td>
        <td class="LP Cell">1,137 LP</td>
            <td class="TeamName Cell">
                        Apex Gaming
                </td>
    <td class="RatioGraph Cell">
                        <div class="WinRatioGraph">
                <div class="Graph">
```

Comment: try using System.out.print(text), it u have newline in text

Comment: can you put your sample html code?

Comment: Yes I can.. added.

Comment: so you want to parse `a` which is inside `td`?

Comment: I already parsed it the problem is, it makes a new line

Comment: @nooby i tried with your sample . i am not getting empty lines . can you post actual input you are trying to parse . i assume there should be `table`,`tr` and i suspect `tr` might be problem. i could not sorted out by that sample why you are getting the lines sorry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trick works for me:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("localhost.com").get();

        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            if (!link.text().isEmpty())
                System.out.println(link.text());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the removal can be tricky as some html tags are always empty as in the case of `<br/> </ img>` etc,

If you can decide which elements of your willing to remove, try the following

```
// Names of the elements to remove if empty
Set<String> ElementsRemove = ....

// Parse the html into a jsoup document
Document source = Jsoup.parse(myHtml);

// Clean the html according to a whitelist

Document cleaned = new Cleaner(whitelist).clean(source);

// For each element in the cleaned document
for(Element el: cleaned.getAllElements()) {

if(el.children().isEmpty() && !el.hasText()) {
   // Element is empty, check if should be removed
   if(removable.contains(el.tagName())) el.remove();
   }
}
```

or  change the *OutputSettings*

```
final String html = ...;
OutputSettings settings = new OutputSettings();
settings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
String cleanHtml = Jsoup.clean(html, "", Whitelist.relaxed(), settings);
```

This is possible with a Document parsed by Jsoup too:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(...);
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
// ...
```